# Notepad++ highlight to copy feature?

Tags: notepad++, copy-paste

Does anyone know if Notepad++ has a unix like copy feature where it automatically copies anything highlighted to your clipboard?

Answer (score 10):

#### Does Notepad++ have a copy feature that automatically copies highlighted text to the clipboard?

Yes. You can use [MultiClipboard 2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/MultiClipboard/MultiClipboard%201.4.1/)
 plugin.

> **Features**
>
> ...
>
> - Option to auto copy selected text from document to clipboard

Source [MultiClipboard 2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/MultiClipboard/MultiClipboard%201.4.1/)