# In Notepad++, how to disable the automatic copying when highlighting?

Tags: notepad++

Whenever I click or highlight a word, it automatically copies it to be pasted. How do I disable it? I only want to copy something when I hit CTRL+C.

Comment: This isn't a standard Notepad++ feature so you should take note of whatever settings you altered or plugins you enabled since installing, since that is where your answer is.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable or delete MultiClipboard plugin from Notepad ++

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/932313/notepad-highlight-to-copy-feature)